# Is a bad idea a cycle in the relationship to try to get better performance?

Tags: database-design

I have this model:

[image]

I have employees, that always do the same tasks in any project in which it is asinged. Also, for a task, the employee need some material, but it is not always the same for a task, but it depends on the project that the task has to be done.

Well, in my case, I want to know the employees of a project, so according to this model I have to get all the tasks of the project and later the employees of the  tasks. So sometimes it could make needed to get a lot of rows.

However, I was wondering if I set a direct relationship between projects and employees, I could get this information directly. But if I am not wrong, this could be a cycle, and I have read that cycles should be avoid.

With materials it would be more or less the same, if I would like to know the materials that I need for a project, I have to get all the tasks and then the materials of each task. I was thinking in the same way, if I want the needed materials for a project, I could set a direct relationship between the project and the materials, so I would avoid duplicates too, because the same material could be needed in many tasks.

If direct relationhips wouldn't be a good idea, were there a better way to retrieve the information, without the need to get all the task in all the queries?

Thanks.

Comment: Make the DB model (schema) according to the required business logic, as close as possible. Indices and query optimizer will do the rest -- that's what relational databases are for. You really do not have the problem described here. One problem that I do see is that the "business requirement" is weird, at best -- likely to result in logical errors later. But, I'm just guessing.

Comment: BTW, in your model you can get all *material* for a *project* from `MaterialsTasksProjects`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be closer to what you seem to be looking for. However, note that this has nothing to do with "performance", see my comment.

```
-- Employee EMP exists.
--
employee {EMP}
      PK {EMP}
```

```
-- Task TSK exists.
--
task {TSK}
  PK {TSK}
```

```
-- Employee EMP is qualified for task TSK.
--
emp_tsk {EMP, TSK}
     PK {EMP, TSK}

FK1 {EMP} REFERENCES employee {EMP}
FK2 {TSK} REFERENCES task     {TSK}
```

```
-- Project PRO exists.
--
project {PRO}
     PK {PRO}
```

```
-- Project PRO requires task TSK.
--
pro_tsk {PRO, TSK}
     PK {PRO, TSK}

FK1 {PRO} REFERENCES project {PRO}
FK2 {TSK} REFERENCES task    {TSK}
```

```
-- Employee EMP is assigned to task TSK
-- of project PRO.
--
emp_pro_tsk {EMP, PRO, TSK}
         PK {EMP, PRO, TSK}

FK1 {PRO, TSK} REFERENCES pro_tsk {PRO, TSK}
FK2 {EMP, TSK} REFERENCES emp_tsk {EMP, TSK}
```

```
-- Material MAT exists.
--
material {MAT}
      PK {MAT}
```

```
-- Material MAT is associated with task TSK.
--
tsk_mat {TSK, MAT}
     PK {TSK, MAT}

FK1 {MAT} REFERENCES material {MAT}
FK2 {TSK} REFERENCES task     {TSK}

-- Note: "associated" means
-- may (or may not) be required.
```

```
-- Material MAT is required for task TSK of project PRO.
--
pro_tsk_mat {PRO, TSK, MAT}
         PK {PRO, TSK, MAT}

FK1 {PRO, TSK} REFERENCES pro_tsk {PRO, TSK}
FK2 {TSK, MAT} REFERENCES tsk_mat {TSK, MAT}
```

Note:

```
All attributes (columns) NOT NULL

PK = Primary Key
AK = Alternate Key   (Unique)
FK = Foreign Key
```